# ShimWarning on running `help("modules")`

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

When running `help("modules")` in python 3.8 (both inside of Jupyter Notebook and in regular python terminal), the following warning appears:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py:12: 
ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.
You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  
warn("The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.")
```

Is there some package or library I need to update in order to resolve this warning? What does it mean to `import from ipykernel or jupyter_client`?

I noticed in the replies to another thread that someone else has run into this exact issue, but no answers. Thanks in advance!